# Error while setting column width in Latex: Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (3cm): `c' used

Tags: tables, tabularx

This is my code to build a simple table.

```
\begin{table}
\small
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l{3cm}|l|l|l}
....
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

But, I am getting the error `Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (3cm):`c' used.`

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: `l{3cm}` isn't allowed because this columntype is not defined with a length. Either use `p{3cm}` or define a new columntype with the `array` package and `\newcolumntype{L}[1]{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}`. You can use `L{3cm}` then

Comment: Use `p{3cm}`. `l` can have no length.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the way to do to it with `array` and `\newcolumntype`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}


\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \small
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{L{3cm}|l|l|R{5cm}}
    A & B & C & D \tabularnewline
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I kept the vertical lines on purpose. Of course, the table does not look well, but that wasn't the question